# jquery table sort once

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

How can I order a table like this:

```
Group pos
b     2
c     1
b     1
a     1
```

to this:

```
Group pos
a     1
b     1
b     2
c     1
```

with jquery?

The table should **not** be **sortable**.

I only want to sort the rows once and I would like to order two columns.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664802/jquery-sorting-a-table-without-the-plugin

Comment: Is this an html table? Are you restricted to not using a plugin? What generates the source data? (could the sorting be applied at source, is generally easier).  What have you tried to so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** to sort the table

```js
$('tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
  var td1 = $(a).find('td'),
    td2 = $(b).find('td');
  // condition for sort - compare with first column if they are equal then compare with second column
  return (td1.eq(0).text() > td2.eq(0).text() || (td1.eq(0).text() == td2.eq(0).text() && td1.eq(1).text() > td2.eq(1).text())) || 0;
}).appendTo('table tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Group</th>
      <th>pos</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        b
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        c
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        b
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        a
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or

```js
$('tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
  var td1 = $(a).find('td'),
    td2 = $(b).find('td');
  // condition for sort - compare with first column if they are equal then compare with second column
  if (td1.eq(0).text() > td2.eq(0).text() || (td1.eq(0).text() == td2.eq(0).text() && td1.eq(1).text() > td2.eq(1).text()))
    return 1;
  else if (td1.eq(0).text() < td2.eq(0).text() || (td1.eq(0).text() == td2.eq(0).text() && td1.eq(1).text() < td2.eq(1).text()))
    return -1;
  return 0;
}).appendTo('table tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Group</th>
      <th>pos</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        b
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        c
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        b
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        a
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```