# sort a table's columns using jquery without plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I am trying to sort a table's column values when specific buttons are clicked. I first want to figure out how to sort the table with pre-defined values (I have included 2 rows with actual values in my table). Second, after I am done with sorting pre-defined values in the table. I want to be able to add a "Create Row" button which can randomly generate any values or even letters. And still, after clicking buttons, values will be sorted. 
My code is broken and I don't know why!

I am stuck and I cannot find much help!! Thanks in advance guys!

```js
//add row function  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var new1 = $("<tr><td>6</td><td>1</td><td><input id ='dr' class='btn btn-danger' type ='button' value= 'delete'></td></tr>").on('click', function() {
      $(this).find('td').toggleClass('highlighted')
    });
    $('#myTable').append(new1);
  });

  //delete function
  $('#myTable').on('click', '#dr', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });


  //sort function 
  $('#sort1,#sort2').on('click', function() {
    var n1 = $(this).index();
    console.log(n1);
    var n2 = $('#myTable').find('tbody >tr:has(td)').get();
    console.log(n2);
    n1 += 1;
    n2.sort(function(a, b) {
      var vA = $(a).children(':nth-child(' + n1 + ')').text();
      var vB = $(b).children(':nth-child(' + n1 + ')').text();
      if (vA < vB) {
        return -1;
      } else if (vA > vB) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0
      };
    });

    $.each(n2, function(index, row) {
      $('tbody').append(row);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>create table</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .highlighted {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

    <table id="myTable" class="table" style="width: 80%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Name<button type="button" id="sort1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></button></td>
          <td>Value<button type="button" id="sort2" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></button></td>
          <td>Deletable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary">Create row</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664802/jquery-sorting-a-table-without-the-plugin) It works fine.

Comment: @Haze, I saw that answer before, but I think it is overly complicated, and it focus heavily on javascript not on jquery. But thanks for your input though!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first row if you change the `<td>` tags to `<th>`s then the sorting will leave them where they are.

```
<th>Name<button type="button" id="sort1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></button></th>
<th>Value<button type="button" id="sort2" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></button></th>
<th>Deletable</th>
```

And in your code when getting the index of the clicked button you always get the index of `$(this)` which is the button's index and not the column's. So try changing that line to

`var n1 = $(this).closest("th").index();`

and it should work.

```js
//add row function  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var new1 = $("<tr><td>6</td><td>1</td><td><input id ='dr' class='btn btn-danger' type ='button' value= 'delete'></td></tr>").on('click', function() {
      $(this).find('td').toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
    $('#myTable').append(new1);
  });

  //delete function
  $('#myTable').on('click', '#dr', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });


  //sort function 
  $('#sort1,#sort2').on('click', function() {
    var n1 = $(this).closest("th").index() + 1;
    console.log(n1 - 1);
    var n2 = $('#myTable').find('tbody >tr:has(td)').get();
    console.log(n2);
    n2.sort(function(a, b) {
      var vA = $(a).children(':nth-child(' + n1 + ')').text();
      var vB = $(b).children(':nth-child(' + n1 + ')').text();
      if (vA < vB) return -1;
      if (vA > vB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });

    $.each(n2, function(index, row) {
      $('tbody').append(row);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>create table</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .highlighted {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

    <table id="myTable" class="table" style="width: 80%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name<button type="button" id="sort1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></button></th>
          <th>Value<button type="button" id="sort2" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></button></th>
          <th>Deletable</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary">Create row</button>
  </div>
</body>
```